# Best method to get a models fields all foreign key id's

Tags: python, django

Lets say i have a model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(user)
```

I want to get that models all user foreign keys
normally i can use,

```
pro = Profile.objects.all()
ids = []
for pros in pro:
  ids.append(pros.user_id)
```

id there a better method?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [`values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#values-list)

```
ids = Profile.objects.values_list('user_id', flat=True)
```

This has the added advantage that only the data you're looking for is returned from the database.

Comment: Add a list to avoid hitting DB for each element access `ids = list(Profile.objects.values_list('user_id', flat=True))`

Comment: @Jinje - list would just evaluate the query, it doesnt avoid any db queries (it wouldnt create multiple queries anyway)